# Como criar um relatório no JasperReports (Jasper Studio) que possua colunas dinamicas?

Tags: jasper-reports

Segue a tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como voces podem ver, as vezes eu posso ter 1 test, 2 test, 3 tests ou as vezes nenhum. Tudo isso ia depender do que eu pudesse trazer do banco. Como eu posso fazer isso no JasperReports?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, hoje mesmo fiz um relatório com colunas dinâmicas.
Só que elas não são tão dinâmicas assim, você vai criar seu relatório, se for nele onde você vai exibir os dados trazidos do banco, você vai nas "properties>advanced>column count" que vai estar marcado com valor 1, e seta o numero de colunas que desejar, marca "print order" de vertical para horizontal, neste caso de tabelas, você pode mandar exibir em uma lista, ai suas colunas ficarão certinhas de acordo com o numero de linhas de cada coluna, caso for usar sub-relatório, o processo é o mesmo. Espero ter ajudado! Dúvidas pergunte! Abraço!